# mostrar el nombre del usuario y no id

Tags: codeigniter, php7

Quiero que muestre el nombre  del usuario que hizo el registro solo logre que mostrara usuarios_id

```
           <?php foreach ($results as $r) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->documento.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($r->registro)).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->descripcion.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->file.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$r->usuarios_id.'</td>'; <!-- Aparesca el nombre no el ID -->
            echo '<td>';
```

[image: Tablas archivos y usuarios]

Comment: Muestranos tu consulta por favor

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio John, no olvides revisar [ask] que te proporciona información para realizar preguntas, estas sean bien recibidas y obtengas la ayuda requerida, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres mostrar el campo `nombre`, pero no parece que sea de la misma tabla de la que obtienes la información en `$result`.

De modo que tienes que obtener ese campo para poder mostrarlo, lo puedes hacer en la misma consulta utilizando un `JOIN` o haciendo una consulta para cada elemento de `$result`. La sentencia SQL sería:

```
SELECT nombre FROM nombre_tabla WHERE idUsuarios = {$r->usuarios_id};
```

Espero que te sirva :-)